# MissingMethodException when calling to a class library from third-party application

Tags: c#, exception, dll

I'm getting a MissingMethodException (referencing a specific method) when calling a method in a company library from a third-party application with scripting, OnBase. The object the method is called on already exists and succeeds other calls before this point.

Things I've confirmed:

- Other references from this library work correctly
- Method is public
- Version of DLL referenced by the script in question has the method (rebuilt the assembly and re-imported it, outputs show current date as created date, and OnBase shows the correct updated version number)
- No versions of the DLL are in the GAC
- Server application has been restarted since importing

Also of note is that the script editor's code completion in OnBase can't find the method either, but it also succeeds building.

- What are the more uncommon locations where I should be looking for an old DLL?
- Are there any OnBase specific locations?
- What other causes can there be?

Comment: Is dll calling another dll that is missing?  Often older Win95 dlls are not directly compatible with Net library so you need a c++ wrapper.  The dll you are calling may be the wrapper and you still need a second dll.

Comment: no luck there unfortunately, the method in question is fairly simple and only uses references from the framework and another library that is used elsewhere and is working correctly there

Comment: Were it is working correctly check the bin folder and see if there are other dlls that you do not have.

Comment: To clarify, assembly 1 is referenced by the script and contains the method that's coming back missing, and assembly 2 is referenced by assembly 1 and the script both. Assembly 2 works in all cases, assembly 1 works except this one method.

Comment: Is everything built with same version of NET? Try backing up the bin folder and delete.  This will cause everything to get rebuilt.  Sometimes when the Net Library gets changes the source files do not get recompiled causing issues like this.

Comment: @jdweng Everything except OnBase here is using 4.5, and changing framework versions for any of it is not an option

Comment: It is a very straight-forward problem, you are simply not loading the DLL that you compiled your program against.  One very basic reason is that it is present in the GAC and did not get its [AssemblyVersion] incremented.  Run Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to see it go wrong.

Comment: @HansPassant what I'm saying is I've checked the obvious places where this could happen, the question is: what are the more uncommon locations, or else what other causes can there be?

Comment: Post the Fuslogvw.exe trace into your question and somebody will give you an exact answer.

Comment: unfortunately I can't add any components or software to the server, and it doesn't already have the viewer installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To clarify, assembly 1 is referenced by the script and contains the method that's coming back missing, and assembly 2 is referenced by assembly 1 and the script both. Assembly 2 works in all cases, assembly 1 works except this one method.

The reason this was happening was that assembly 1 and the script were referencing different versions of assembly 2, so when we were trying to pass in an object defined in assembly 2 to the method in assembly 1, it was from a version that didn't match and so what was missing was a method with that specific signature, i.e. DoStuff(v1.Foo) existed but DoStuff(v2.Foo) didn't. Obviously, the error only stated that DoStuff(Foo) was missing.